# accept a series of number? for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, numbers

I'm new into the programming stuff so i'm not sure how to write a program that will accept a series of numbers and will exit only if the user enters 0 then display how many numbers were entered before the user enters 0.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Sample {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        int y;
        int count = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter any number to continue. Enter 0 to stop.");
        num = x.nextInt();
        for(int n = 0; n<=num; n++) { //is this for loop right?
            y = x.nextInt();
            count += y;
        }
        if(num == 0){
            System.out.printf("You entered %d numbers,count");
        }
    }
} // i know my code is missing alot.
```

Output Should be like this.

```
Enter any number to continue. Enter 0 to stop 
12
11
5
6
1
0
You entered 6 numbers.
2 even
3 odd // i know my code is far from what i want my output to be.
EDIT :
if the user enters 2 then 0 the output should be
You Entered an even number // same with odd. how?
```

Comment: Why those close vote? It might be an exercise, but at least the OP made a reasonable attempt.

Comment: @NickJ Possibly because the poster hasn't asked a question or described what problem they are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Working demo here](https://ideone.com/zS9WJK)

---

You're close, just get variables for each count, and check it inside the while loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = 0; // to store user's enter
    int odd = 0, count = 0, even = 0; // to store all counts

    System.out.print("Enter any number to continue. Enter 0 to stop.");
    // ask for first number
    num = x.nextInt();
    
    // loop until 0 is entered
    while (num != 0) {
        // each time sum 1 because new number entered
        count ++;
        // if num / 2 modulus is 0 then even number 
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            even ++;
        // if num / 2 modulus is not 0 then odd number 
        } else {
            odd ++;
        }

        // ask for a new number
        num = x.nextInt();
    }

    // print the results
    System.out.printf("You entered %d numbers\n",count);
    System.out.printf("You entered %d even numbers\n",even);
    System.out.printf("You entered %d odd numbers\n",odd);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Enter any number to continue. Enter 0 to stop.
12
11
5
6
1
0

You entered 6 numbers
You entered 2 even numbers
You entered 3 odd numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

Some clues:

Your line

```
num = x.nextInt();
```

Will likely cause a compilation error because you have not declared the variable `num`.

Also, your loop should continue **while** the number is greater than 0. To do this, use a **while** loop:

```
int num = 1; //some non-zero starting number
while (num != 0) {
    num = x.nextInt();
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code is self describing

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        int odd = 0, even = 0, num = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter any number to continue. Enter 0 to stop.");
        while ((num = x.nextInt()) != 0) {

            if (num % 2 == 0) {
                even++;
            } else {
                odd++;
            }

        }
        System.out.printf("\nYou entered %d numbers\n", even + odd);
        System.out.printf("even %d\n", even);
        System.out.printf("odd %d\n", odd);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your logic as   in ttwo ways  process numbers as inserted or process all after insertion of 0 
Below example for Process as inserted
While ( true) 
{
      read line
      check if  zero
        break ;
      else
         check if odd
            increment  odd nos count
          else
             increment evens nos count
}
display  what you want to

Second scenario --

While ( true) 
{
      read line
      check if  zero
        break ;
      else
            add no to  list 
}

for each entry in list
{
        check if odd
            increment  odd nos count
          else
             increment evens nos count
}
display  what you want to

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Enter any number to continue. Enter 0 to stop.");
while (true) {
    int num = x.nextInt() ;

    if (num == 0) {
       break;
    }

    if (num % 2 == 0) {
       even++;
    } else {
       odd++;
    }

    count++;
}
```